# What time have you kept your money for?

Tags: grammar, questions

Is it correct to ask "What time have you kept your money for?" as a question to mean "Why have you saved your money?"? 
The answer is, "For a rainy day!"

Comment: Both sentence are grammatical. They mean different things. Or at least *what time* is a small subset of *why*, and the answer to *why* could have nothing to do with time at all. ("*Why have you saved your money?" "My investment advisor told me to."*)

Comment: I would find "_When_ have you saved your money for?" perfectly natural, but also a "stupid question", because everybody knows why people save money.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you imply that "What time have you saved your money for?" is not natural English? By the way, we save money for different reasons! I may save my money to buy a new car in two years. But you may save your money to travel around the world after the pandemic!

Comment: "What time" is usually employed when talking about clock times, e.g. 3.15pm.

Comment: If you simply asked me, “What time have you kept your money for.” I would have no idea what you meant and thus how I should answer.  I’d have to ask “what do you mean?”  I think, “What are you saving [up] for?” would be much more likely to be understand immediately.  But I can imagine being at a carnival where they were having drawings every hour.  The drawing at 5:00pm is for a new TV.  I ask, “Why aren’t you buying any tickets for the 3 o’clock drawing?”  He says “I’m not interested in the 3 o’clock drawing.” I might say “Ok, what time have you kept you money for?” “I’m waiting for 5:00”